# vue-google-autocomplete & nuxt 2.1.0 - cannot nuxt-generate it - error when loading the page

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm having problems when loading the page containing `vue-google-autocomplete` module. the problem is shown below

```
✖ error /.../node_modules/vue-google-autocomplete/src/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue:1
  (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <template>
  ^

  SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
  at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
  at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
  at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
  at r (/Users/dariorusignuolo/Desktop/phpstorm/jukemotion-booking/jukemotion-booking-client/node_modules/nuxt/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:8341:16)
  at Object.vue-google-autocomplete (server-bundle.js:8677:18)
  at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
  at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/form/j-search.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (components/form/j-search.vue?cfb9:1:0)
  at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0)
  at Module../components/form/j-search.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (components/form/j-search.vue?00ca:1:0)
```

The version is `1.1.0` (the latest) and the nuxt version is `2.1.0` while the node version is `10.4.1`

I'm facing the exact problem even when starting the `nuxt generate` command.

Tried also loading globally with placing the load of this module inside the plugins using

`Vue.component('vue-google-autocomplete', VueGoogleAutocomplete);`

without any luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to transpile it. See nuxt [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#templates)

```
  build: {
    ...
    transpile: ['vue-google-autocomplete']
  }
```